# Exceptions in live stream not appearing in analytics

Tags: asp-classic, azure-application-insights

I have a sitecore application and I'm using the app insights sdk, I'm seeing the requests and some exceptions in both the live stream and analytics. But some exception on certain pages are appearing in the live stream, but not the analytics.

I've removed the adaptive sampling and ensured no ingestion filtering, other items like traces are coming through.

Comment: One possible reason is that live stream is almost real-time, but for analytics, it always has some minutes delay.

Comment: I'm seeing the requests and the traces within a few mins but the exception never comes through

Comment: how do you check it in analytics? ui or query?

Comment: a query in the portal

Comment: is it a .net core web app(I see you say sitecore application)? if you're using visual studio for the test, please take a look at if the exception telemetry data can be shown locally -> in the visual studio output window

Comment: It's not .net core, its classic .net, I can see the exception data in  visual studio

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the exception data in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Default configuration in Application Insights will decide to either sample or not at the beginning of a request and then correspondingly either will collect everything or drop everything. This approach provides some guarantees such as if you're looking at some transaction then you see it entirely, including some downstream components.

You're right that with this approach it is possible miss some errors.Following things you can try:

- Collect all exceptions. For this you can modify the following adaptive sampling section like below:

  5
          Event,Exception
      
    
      100
      Exception
    
    
          5
          Event
- It is possible to write own sampling processor (TelemetryProcessor). For instance, collect failed requests, dependencies, exceptions and for the rest apply own sampling logic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had removed all the sampling and I can see the exception in the live stream with the 500 request, but in analytics the 500 request shows, but not the exception